# Standard SQL - CHAR to ASCII

Tags: sql, char, ascii, standards

Using standard SQL, SQL-92, how can I convert a character to an ASCII value?

In MySQL it's easy using the ascii() function, but SQL-92 doesn't have this.

Comment: I'd have to guess that the ANSI SQL standards (92 et. al) are media-agnostic. ASCII, EBcIDIC, and other physical implementation details are irrelevant to relational theory.

Answer (score 5):

**It appears** the [SQL-92 standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) doesn't even mention ASCII at all.

As you say, each RDBMS vendor would have its own implementation how to convert char->ascii and ascii->char.

Most name this function `ASCII()`.

- [SQL Server  ASCII](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177545.aspx)
- [Postgresql ASCII](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)
- [Oracle ASCII](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ASCII)
- [MySQL ASCII](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ascii)

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table with all the ASCII characters and their corresponding values -- [there are only 127 of them](http://www.asciitable.com/) -- and then just do `SELECT [value] FROM [table] WHERE [character] = 'A'` etc.